# PHPMailer "CharSet" incompatibility with "AltBody" and "AddEmbeddedImage" at the same time

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have this code where sending body in UTF-8 is not working:

```
<?php
    require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img_00/Mailing_febrero2015_02.jpg', 'fondo', 'fondo.jpg');
    $mail->Body = 'árbol'; 
    if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

But if I remove the "AltBody" or "AddEmbeddedImage" it sends correctly in UTF-8. Why this occurs (I have the last PHPMailer version)?
There is another correct way to add an alternative body and embedded image at the same time?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it looks correctly-encoded to me. One thing - using an embedded image without HTML doesn't make much sense, I'd suggest `addAttachment` for that. If you are using HTML with embedded images, you may find it easier to use `msgHTML`.

Comment: I only have this problem when the receiver is Outlook 2007.

Comment: You need to define 'not working' and provide an example of an incorrectly-encoded message.

Comment: If I check the email with Outlook 2007 I see:
"Ã¡rbol"

If I check with webmail account or the receiver is a gmail account, I see:
"árbol"